# Non-determinism in encoding when using open() with scalar and I/O layers in Perl

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, perl, perl-io

For several hours now I am fighting a bug in my Perl program. I am not sure if I do something wrong or the interpreter does, but the code is non-deterministic while it should be deterministic, IMO. Also it exhibits the same behavior on ancient Debian Lenny (Perl 5.10.0) and a server just upgraded to Debian Wheezy (Perl 5.14.2). It boiled down to this piece of Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
binmode STDERR, ":utf8";
my $c = "";
open C, ">:utf8", \$c;
print C "š";
close C;
die "Does not happen\n" if utf8::is_utf8($c);
print utf8::decode($c) ? "Decoded\n" : "Undecoded\n";
```

It initializes Perl 5 interpreter in strict mode with warnings enabled, with character strings (as opposed to byte strings) and named standard streams encoded in UTF8 (internal notion of UTF-8, but pretty close; changing to full UTF-8 makes no difference). Then it opens a file handle to an “in-memory file” (scalar variable), prints a single two-byte UTF-8 character into it and examines the variable upon closure.

The scalar variable now always has UTF8 bit flipped off. However it sometimes contains a byte string (converted to character string via `utf8::decode()`) and sometimes a character string that just needs to flip on its UTF8 bit (`Encode::_utf8_on()`).

When I execute my code repeatedly (1000 times, via Bash), it prints `Undecoded` and `Decoded` with approximately the same frequencies. When I change the string I write into the “file”, e.g. add a newline at its end, `Undecoded` disappears. When `utf8::decode` succeeds and I try it for the same original string in a loop, it keeps succeeding in the same instance of interpreter; however, if it fails, it keeps failing.

**What is the explanation for the observed behavior? How can I use file handle to a scalar variable together with character strings?**

Bash playground:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do perl -we 'use strict; use utf8; binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; binmode STDERR, ":utf8"; my $c = ""; open C, ">:utf8", \$c; print C "š"; close C; die "Does not happen\n" if utf8::is_utf8($c); print utf8::decode($c) ? "Decoded\n" : "Undecoded\n";'; done | grep Undecoded | wc -l
```

For reference and to be absolutely sure, I also made a version with pedantic error handling – same results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8" or die "Cannot binmode STDOUT\n";
binmode STDERR, ":utf8" or die "Cannot binmode STDERR\n";
my $c = "";
open C, ">:utf8", \$c or die "Cannot open: $!\n";
print C "š" or die "Cannot print: $!\n";
close C or die "Cannot close: $!\n";
die "Does not happen\n" if utf8::is_utf8($c);
print utf8::decode($c) ? "Decoded\n" : "Undecoded\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examining `$c` in details reveals it has nothing to do with the content of `$c` or its internals, and the result of `decode` accurately represents what it did or didn't do.

```
$ for i in {1..2}; do
     perl -MDevel::Peek -we'
        use strict; use utf8;
        binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
        binmode STDERR, ":utf8";
        my $c = "";
        open C, ">:utf8", \$c;
        print C "š";
        close C;
        die "Does not happen\n" if utf8::is_utf8($c);
        Dump($c);
        print utf8::decode($c) ? "Decoded\n" : "Undecoded\n";
        Dump($c)
     '
     echo
  done
```

```
SV = PV(0x17c8470) at 0x17de990
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x17d7a40 "\305\241"
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
Decoded
SV = PV(0x17c8470) at 0x17de990
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x17d7a40 "\305\241" [UTF8 "\x{161}"]
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
```

```
SV = PV(0x2d0fee0) at 0x2d26400
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2d1f4b0 "\305\241"
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
Undecoded
SV = PV(0x2d0fee0) at 0x2d26400
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x2d1f4b0 "\305\241"
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 16
```

This was a bug in `utf8::decode`, but it was fixed in 5.16.3 or earlier, probably 5.16.0 since it was still present in 5.14.2.

A suitable workaround it to use Encode's `decode_utf8` instead.

Comment: I managed to find the bug. Its [Perl bug #82772](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=82772) fixed in [commit f9cf141af97dff1d857ee2f905962a19ac97fc36](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/f9cf141af97dff1d857ee2f905962a19ac97fc36), which is first included in v5.15.8. Thanks to Corion from PerlMonks.org for help with locating `Perl_sv_utf8_decode` in Perl source and GitHub for enabling me to work with the repo (specifically find I need to read Perl_sv_utf8_decode and read its blame) without downloading tons of data.